# Difference EXECUTE AS targets

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, permissions, execute

I am not quite clear about the difference between different [EXECUTE AS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) targets in SQL Server : `CALLER`, `SELF` and `OWNER`, notably between the last two.

My understanding is that CALLER is the one who Execute/Call the procedure.

SELF is `the specified user is the person creating or altering the module`

OWNER is `the current owner of the module`

Could you explain and give some example who is `the person creating/modifying` and `the owner of the module`. Is 'module' here the stored procedure/function or the session or the database ? Including an example with `SELF` user will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being put very simple, `SELF` impersonates you as a database user who actually executed `create / alter procedure` the last time. It doesn't always have to be the schema owner, as you can imagine, it can be any person with permissions sufficient to create / modify given objects.

The `OWNER` mode impersonates you as the owner of the schema the procedure / function belongs to.

If you want to dig a little deeper (and is this case, there is always some room to dig in), below is a (relatively) simple example that can demonstrate you how things can work here. There are some shortcuts and implications that are specific to SQL Server which I omit deliberately because otherwise it would be too much to write. You can always read the documentation, though.

```
use master;
go
if db_id('TestDB') is not null
    drop database TestDB;
go
create database TestDB;
go
use TestDB;
go
-- Just for the sake of example, so that everyone can create procs
grant create procedure to public;
go
-- Schema owner
create user [SomeUser] without login;
go
create schema [s1] authorization [SomeUser];
go
-- An ordinary user
create user [AnotherUser] without login;
go
grant execute on schema::s1 to AnotherUser as [SomeUser];
go
-- Database administrator
create user [DBA] without login;
go
alter role [db_owner] add member [DBA];
go

-- Although it's SomeUser that owns the schema, DBA creates objects in it
execute as user = 'DBA';
go
create procedure s1.SpCaller
as
select user_name() as [s1_caller];
return;
go
create procedure s1.SpSelf
with execute as self as
select user_name() as [s1_self];
return;
go
create procedure s1.SpOwner
with execute as owner as
select user_name() as [s1_owner];
return;
go
revert;
go

-- You can play with actual impersonation and look at results
execute as user = 'AnotherUser';
go
exec s1.SpCaller;
go
exec s1.SpSelf;
go
exec s1.SpOwner;
go
revert;
go
```